# Как обнулить массив

Tags: массивы, javascript

Как можно быстро удалить все элементы из массива, который уже был объявлен ранее?

```
$arr=null;
```

удаляет сам массив, а не его содержимое.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Быть может я чего-то не понял, но:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
array = []; // :D
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось.

Comment: На здоровье =)

Comment: это не очищает массив, а создает новый пустой массив. Очевидная ошибка: если где-то в коде есть места где использовалась переменная array, то после выполнения `array = [];`, в других местах кода массив не будет очищен.

Answer (score 12):

```
arr.splice(0,arr.length);
```

или

```
arr.length=0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Я только начинаю знакомство с *JS*, и сам набрел на этот форум в поисках ответа на поставленный вопрос.

Вроде как нашел его в методе `arr.shift();`. Этот метод очищает 0 ячейку массива.

Можно сделать цикл по очистке массива например, а быть может есть и более эффективные способы.

Answer (score -1):

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
array.splice(0, array.length)
```

Comment: чем этот вариант отличается от самого заплюсованного ответа?